# make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE ....... Error 2 while installing rtl8723de wifi drivers

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, gnu-make, debian-buster

### I was trying to install rtl8712de wifi drivers in my Debian 10 PC.

I tried the following code:

---

```
sudo apt update
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git
cd rtl8723de
make
```

---

After I ran the `make` command, I got the following error:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules//build M=/home/dantu/Downloads/rtl8723de  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules//build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1886: modules] Error 2
```

---

I tried so many steps online. I installed gcc build tools, updated all my packages, tried other repositories for the wifi drivers. But nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

It might solve the problem to change all occurrences of /lib/modules//build inside the Makefile with /lib/modules/build or /lib/modules/your_kernel_version/build. //build seem like a typo.